# Can't see Spark gc log

Tags: apache-spark

I submitted my jar file using this:

```
spark-submit \
--class Hello \
--master spark://master:7077  \
--num-executors 6 \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedOops" \
first.jar
```

You could see that I added the `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedOops` part as recommended in the official documentation. However, when  I look at the slaves' `stdout`and `stderr`in the web UI , I could see nothing about Garbage Collection.

Is it the log4j setting preventing showing of gc log? I only have the `log4j.properties.template` file inside my spark's `conf` directory.

Any suggestions on what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: When you look in the Spark UI under environment, do you see these flags there?

Comment: Yes, I could see those flags in the environment tab, I also checked the "out" log in slaves, I could see that the slave is start using those flags. So I really stuck at this, the whole Internet contains only posts about how to use gc information to optimize spark...Orz

Comment: What do you see in the Spark Executor logs? Do you see normal Spark stuff?

Comment: Yes, It's totally normal spark stuff..lilke `16/09/23 21:18:43 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 24
16/09/23 21:18:43 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_24_....`

Comment: Strange, I change a spark version and my jar file encounter a major memory problem, and now spark is showing gc logs. I wonder may be it has something to do with the log delay cause by buffer?

Comment: I didn't understand that last comment. What exactly did you change?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html - the GC Logs are written into:
`$SPARK_HOME/work/$app_id/$executor_id/stdout`

Try configuring your spark app with the settings suggested on this page and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can add these jvm param to

> -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=3 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M

to

> spark.executor.extraJavaOptions

it will start logging gc logs to

> $SPARK_HOME/work/$app_id/$executor_id/gc.log.0.current